# How to use EEG on dogs?

Tags: eeg, animal-cognition

I need to take EEG readings on dogs for BCI and seizure prediction research. To do so do I need special equipment?

Is there an accepted approach in terms of frequency, electrode size and placement, etc?

Comment: Can you expand you question, and explain why you want to do it? I think, the "approach in terms of frequency, electrode size and placement" will be much more obvious.

Comment: @EmptyBrain Sure, I updated it a bit just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick google search I (surprisingly) found that it already has an application: the [No More Woof headset](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2526360/The-headset-lets-DOG-talk-Prototype-analyses-pets-thoughts-translates-human-speech.html).

I believe the most important part is that you have a headset that fits and does not move when a dog walks or turns his head. Then it does not matter that much where and how the electrodes are oriented. The only thing you need to do is map the locations of the available electrodes to correct brain-regions of a dog. For human studies there are many different layouts of EEG caps ([FieldTrip](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/template/layout)), which is fine, because they have such a clear mapping to brain areas.

How a dog's brain looks like and what frequencies can be expected I do not know, however. Perhaps you can follow up on the "No More Woof" to see what references they used to base their approach on.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I'm surprised that it wouldn't matter where the electrodes are positioned though. Isn't that important to knowing what areas of the brain are being measured? I like the "Woof No More" product except that it looks like it only has 1 or 2 channels, whereas for research grade analysis I'm going to need at least 14. I might be able to design something custom based on this though.

Comment: Knowing which areas you measure is what I meant with "map the locations of the available electrodes". Some caps measure the POz location, others do not. Having a particular electrode is thus not of vital importance, but knowing which areas are being measured IS.